# Set-Cookie header not setting a cookie with SameSite=None attribute

Tags: authentication, cookies, prestashop, samesite, third-party-cookies

I'm trying to make a request from a client located on the domain **a.com** to a server running PrestaShop on the domain **b.com**. My goal is to obtain a cookie containing an authentication token. Although I do receive a Set-Cookie header that contains the token and has attributes: **expires=Sun, 08-Oct-2023 19:25:34 GMT; Max-Age=1728000; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None,** the cookie is not being stored in the browser. Both domains are secured with SSL certificates.

Comment: the cookie will be associated with `b.com` are you verifying that cookie jar?

Comment: But shouldn't the SameSite=None attribute allow sending cookies to another domain?